# Titanium - TextField keyboard type for words first letter capital letter

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have a `TextField` in a registration form that is for entering a full name. I would like each letter of the name to be upper case (each word is part of the name).

I tried using `keyboardType: Ti.UI.KEYBOARD_TYPE_NAMEPHONE_PAD` but that doesn't always work - it works if iPhone auto correct the sur-name that was entered.

I remember such property for upper-casing each word existed... what `keyboardType` should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the property autocapitalization : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextField-property-autocapitalization

like this :

```
autocapitalization : Titanium.UI.TEXT_AUTOCAPITALIZATION_WORDS
```

Comment: Can you please mention the SDK that you are working on, because it doesn't  seems work for me with SDK 5.3.1 GA.